# Can OS Erroneosly Report Hard Drive As Encrypted When It Isn't?

Tags: boot, encryption

I was trying to remove the old kernels from my /boot partition after updating to the newest one (because somehow that partition was created pretty small) and I think I accidentally deleted the newest one.

I was only putting the laptop to sleep whenever I wasn't using it, so a couple weeks went by before I restarted it. I got the message something like "cannot find /boot/vmlunuz 4.8.59 (numbers probably wrong) then: "You need to load the kernel first!" (at least it didn't append "dumb-ass!" to it lol!).

So, I booted off a live Ubuntu CD, but now it is telling me that the hard drive is "encrypted" and asking me for a password.
I don't remember ever encrypting it. Could that be an erroneous message?

If I did encrypt it, I would have used the same password I use for almost everything (I know that's not recommended, but...) depending upon whether at least one number or one symbol or both upper and lower cases are required, I have variations of the same password; and I've tried all of them.

(Unless the password had to have been at least 16 characters or something; but then I would have repeated the same from the beginning in order to pad it).

I'm close to just formatting the hard drive and putting a nice, fresh Ubuntu on it and calling it a new beginning; but it sure would be nice to have the past year's work back; -275 gigs of my own music in Audacity files, for example.
Thank you, in advance for any advice

Comment: Basically, my hard drive that had Ubuntu 16.01 on it; I messed up by deleting the /boot/vmlinuz file which was the most recent one that I got through the software updater app; then, when I booted a live CD and tried to look at the drive, I got the message saying it was LUKS encrypted; but I don't remember encrypting it; could my cmos battery have gone dead and the bios can't find vmlinuz that way??

Comment: I just went and did a fresh installation, kissing my data goodbye...it felt unethical to be asking how to crack into an encrypted drive; and I can understand the reluctance of the community to offer help LOL!